# Why can the article “die” lead a clause in this sentence?

Tags: subordinate-clause, grammar-identification

In [this article](http://www.nachrichtenleicht.de/musik-preise.2045.de.html?dram:article_id=383219) I got stuck by this sentence:

> Die Echos bekommen Musiker, die mit ihren Liedern besonders
>   erfolgreich sind.

If I am correct I can translate it (with the help of Google Translate) to:

> The Echo prizes are awarded to those who are particularly successful with their songs.

I am not familiar with the new grammar that *die mit* leads a clause, especially the article die here. What is happening here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Die* here is not a definite article. It is the plural form (the same, "die," for all three genders) of the relative pronoun *which* / *that* / *who* (depending in English on the antecedent in the main clause, which in this case is the masculine noun *der Musiker* in the plural, *(die) Musiker*).

One way to make sure this is correct is the following sequence:

> Die Echos [plural] ... bekommen [plural] ... Musiker [plural] ... die [plural] ... sind [plural].